# How to use pymongo to find the result with limited characters

Tags: python, pymongo

I need to find the result with postype 2 and sort it by Score from high to low. The final result's body part will only display 80 characters (if it has less than 80, it will display all of the body). I am confused with how to combine them together and i write the part of code.

```
climit = {"$redact":{"$cond":[{"$gt":[{"strlenCP":"$name"},80]},"$$KEEP","$$PRUNE"]}}

ctype = {"$match":{"PostTypeId" : 2}}
search = [ctype,climit]
ret = posts_collection.find(ctype)
for i in ret:
    print(i)
```

my data looks like that

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fbcf481fc6360b2e1922476"),
  "Id" : "99",
  "PostTypeId" : "1",
  "AcceptedAnswerId" : "103",
  "CreationDate" : "2010-08-17T20:31:26.913",
  "Score" : 9,
  "ViewCount" : 5880,
  "Body" : "<p>Is there a way to tell Finder to not use (or worry about) the ._* files and other meta-data files it normally tries to use when it's on a network share?</p>\n\n<p>Currently when I'm in Finder and I try to copy a file to a network share it results in an error:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n  <p>The Finder can’t complete the\n  operation because some data in “file_name” can’t be read or written.\n  (Error code -36)</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>But I can copy the file from the terminal command line to the network share and use it from Finder afterward just fine.  It seems that the meta-data isn't really needed on the network share.  Is there a way to tell Finder this?</p>\n\n<p>For reference, I'm using Snow Leopard and the share is a Samba share on a Linux server.</p>\n",
  "OwnerUserId" : "41",
  "LastActivityDate" : "2018-11-21T01:21:42.893",
  "Title" : "Dot-files and other meta data on non-Mac network shares",
  "Tags" : "<finder><samba>",
  "AnswerCount" : 4,
  "CommentCount" : 1,
  "FavoriteCount" : 4,
  "ContentLicense" : "CC BY-SA 2.5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data `PostTypeId` is a string, so you must filter on `"2"` (or `'2'`) and not `2`.

To trim the field you could wrestle with an aggregate query and `$strlenCP`, but if you're using pymongo just use `[:80]` in python.

Example:

```
from pymongo import DESCENDING
ret = posts_collection.find({'PostTypeId' : '2'}).sort('Score', DESCENDING)

for record in ret:
    print(record.get('Body', '')[:80])
```